# Is it possible to render a Razor Page (not partial View) using <partial>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, razor-pages

I'm new on Razor MVC and I'm struggling to do something very simple (I suppose).

I have a razor page (not a PartialView), and I want to load it in a bootstrap modal. I'm trying to use  or Html.RenderPartial, but the models are not the same, so I have the following error:

> The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type
>   'ProjectName.Pages.AdminPageModel', but this ViewDataDictionary
>   instance requires a model item of type
>   'ProjectName.Pages.CreatePublisherPageModel'.

Please help me!

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The partial tag helper is for rendering partials, i.e. razor files with no `@page` directive. If you have some common UI that you want to share between the Razor page and the modal, put that in a partial and use the tag helper in both the page and the modal.